# How to define multiple blocks in a module?

Tags: 7, blocks

Thanks to [this tutorial](https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2014/01/15/beginning-drupal-module-development-custom-drupal-blocks-tutorial), I cam up with this block-generating module:

```
function myblockmodule_block_info(){
    $block['myadblocks'] = array(
        'info' => t('My first ad blcoks'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $block;
}

/**
 * Define what our block is going to look like.
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function myblockmodule_block_view($block_key){
    $block = array();

    if($block_key == 'myadblocks'){ //We only want to define the content of OUR block
        //This is the title of the block.
        $block['subject'] = t('First ad block comes here');

        //Define the block content.
        $block['content'] = 'some fancy script comes here';
    }

    return $block;
}
```

I am wondering how to extend the module to create 2 blocks instead of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple as:

```
function myblockmodule_block_info(){
    $block['myadblocks'] = array(
        'info' => t('My first ad blcoks'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );

    $block['myadblocks2'] = array(
        'info' => t('My second ad blcoks'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $block;
}

/**
 * Define what our block is going to look like.
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function myblockmodule_block_view($block_key){
    $block = array();

    if($block_key == 'myadblocks'){ //We only want to define the content of OUR block
        //This is the title of the block.
        $block['subject'] = t('First ad block comes here');

        //Define the block content.
        $block['content'] = 'some fancy script comes here';
    }
    elseif ($block_key == 'myadblocks2') {
      $block['subject'] = t('Foo');
      $block['content'] = 'var';
    }

    return $block;
}
```

And clear the caches.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myblockmodule_block_info(){
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['myadblocks'] = array(
        'info' => t('My first ad blcoks'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    $blocks['myadblocks2'] = array(
        'info' => t('My second ad block'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Define what our block is going to look like.
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function myblockmodule_block_view($block_key){
    $block = array();

    if($block_key == 'myadblocks'){ //We only want to define the content of OUR block
        //This is the title of the block.
        $block['subject'] = t('First ad block comes here');

        //Define the block content.
        $block['content'] = 'some fancy script comes here';
    } elseif ($block_key == 'myadblocks2') {

        $block['subject'] = t('Second ad block comes here');

        $block['content'] = 'some fancy script comes here';
    }

    return $block;
}
```

Comment: Seems Clive got in first :)

Comment: Nah @AyeshK, we just picked the same array key ;)

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a 1:1. Didn't realize OP used the same block keys.

Comment: Thanks man. I chosen Clove as he responded a bit sooner. I appreciate if you comment on the follow up question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144342/is-this-block-safe-from-code-injection-exploit